# Can newtonian particles using an Object as the render method, have unique rotation angles?

Tags: particles

Following this guide http://blendersushi.blogspot.ca/2011/07/randomization-using-blender-particle.html

I created a particle system , but each newtonian particle is using the same rotation. I have selected 'Object' as the render type setting. So each one of my objects is copying the 'reference' objects rotation angle....

Can each particle somehow be given a random rotation? I want a 'Boids' random effect, but with the newtonian setting so I can push the particles through some nearby fields.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a *Rotation* panel with rotation options in the Particle settings, including a *Random* property

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos sorry, to make it clear I am using an object as the particle render setting, so like the link tutorial i gave, all particles have the same rotation equal to their reference object.